# Remote bookmarks in Mercurial to keep new features separate

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to use bookmarks in Mercurial to share new features with other developers. I have followed the basic workflow as they appear [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-bookmarks) or [here](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/bookmarks/). In short:

```
$ hg bookmark main
$ hg bookmark feature
$ hg update feature
$ hg commit -m "changes"
$ hg push -B feature
```

My main problem is that at this point my changes are not separate from the default branch, and if someone else does

```
$ hg pull
$ hg update
```

in their working directory, they get my changes, too, which is not intended - I would like them to do `hg update feature` to get them.

I figure if I then commit something (an empty commit maybe) to `main` and push that as well, all is well and `feature` appears separate. But is there a better way achieving the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial knows the special bookmark `@`. Attach that to a commit which is updated to by default.

See also [the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Bookmarks), section 5.

Comment: Thanks. It does work when cloning, but if I just update, it still updates to the tip which may be ahead of my bookmark